# Regression coefficient when eliminating a row

Tags: statistics

I have a problem understanding the proof of the following proposition that gives the expression of the regression coefficients when removing a row from the design matrix.
The demo says the following:
It's known that,
$X^tX=\sum_{k=1}^n \overrightarrow{x_k}\overrightarrow{x_k^t}=X^t_{-i}X_{-i}+\overrightarrow{x_i}\overrightarrow{x_i}$
applying the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury theorem,
$(X_{-1}^tX_{-i})^{-1}=(XX^t)^{-1}+\frac{(X^tX)^{-1}\overrightarrow{x_i}\overrightarrow{x_i^t}(X^tX)^{-1}}{1-h_{ii}}$
my problem comes now, since from here it concludes directly,
$\widehat{\beta_{-i}}=(X_{-1}^tX_{-i})^{-1}X^t_{-i}\overrightarrow{y_{-i}}=\widehat{\beta}+\frac{1}{1-h_{ii}}(X^tX)^{-1}\overrightarrow{x_i}e_i$

and I am not able to understand that last step.
Please if someone can explain to me why that product gives that expression at the end, I try to introduce the inverse expression, but I don't see where the beta is coming from, and I'm very involved with the issue of X and y Without the i-th row, it seems to me that something needs to be added or done to solve it, which I am not able to see.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a careful derivation. Let $X$ be the $n\times p$ design matrix, and let the $p\times 1$ column vector $x_i$ hold the $i$th row of $X$. Let $X_{-i}$ be the design matrix with row $i$ removed. Check that
$$X^\top X=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k x_k^\top\tag1$$ and $$
X_{-i}^\top X_{-i}=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k x_k^\top-x_ix_i^\top=X^\top X-x_ix_i^\top\tag2
$$
so by the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)
$$
(X_{-i}^\top X_{-i})^{-1}=(X^\top X)^{-1} + \frac{(X^\top X)^{-1}x_ix_i^\top (X^\top X)^{-1}}{1-x_i^\top (X^\top X)^{-1} x_i},\tag3
$$
For brevity write $A:=(X^\top X)^{-1}$. Introduce the hat matrix
$ H:=XAX^\top$
and observe that the $(i,i)$ element of $H$ is
$$h_{ii}=x_i^\top Ax_i\tag4
$$ so we can rewrite (3) as
$$ (X_{-i}^\top X_{-i})^{-1}=A + \frac{Ax_ix_i^\top A}{1-h_{ii}}.\tag5
$$ Let $y$ be the $n\times 1$ vector of responses $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)^\top$. If $y_{-i}$ denotes the vector of responses with element $i$ removed, then
$$
X_{-i}^\top y_{-i}=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k-x_iy_i=X^\top y-x_iy_i.\tag6
$$
Combining (5) and (6) we have
$$
\widehat{\beta_{-i}}=(X_{-i}^\top X_{-i})^{-1}X_{-i}^\top y_{-i}=\left( A + \frac{Ax_ix_i^\top A}{1-h_{ii}}\right)\left(X^\top y-x_i y_i\right).\tag7$$
Expand the RHS of (7) as a sum of the following four terms:
$$
\begin{aligned}
AX^\top y &= \hat\beta\\
\frac{Ax_ix_i^\top A}{1-h_{ii}}X^\top y &=\frac{Ax_ix_i^\top\hat\beta}{1-h_{ii}}\\
-Ax_iy_i&=-\frac{(1-h_{ii})A x_iy_i}{1-h_{ii}}\\
-\frac{Ax_ix_i^\top A}{1-h_{ii}}x_iy_i&\stackrel{(4)}=-\frac{Ax_ih_{ii}y_i}{1-h_{ii}}
\end{aligned}\tag8
$$
Collecting these and cancelling yields
$$
\widehat{\beta_{-i}}=\hat\beta + \frac{Ax_ix_i^\top\hat\beta}{1-h_{ii}}-\frac{A x_iy_i}{1-h_{ii}}
=
\hat\beta + \frac{Ax_i(x_i^\top\hat\beta-y_i)}{1-h_{ii}}.\tag9
$$
In (9) we recognize the $i$th residual $e_i:=y_i-x_i^\top\hat\beta $. This demonstrates
$$
\widehat{\beta_{-i}}=\hat\beta -\frac{(X^\top X)^{-1}x_ie_i}{1-h_{ii}}.\tag{10}
$$